# Getting X,Y coordinate with mouse click on vertex of line feature using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, mapcanvas

How do I get X,Y coordinate with mouse click with enabling snapping so that only line's vertex point coordinates will be selected?

By using following code I can get latitude longitude of clicked position in map canvas of QGIS but cannot enable the snapping option .

```
from qgis.gui import QgsMapToolEmitPoint
class PrintClickedPoint(QgsMapToolEmitPoint):
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        QgsMapToolEmitPoint.__init__(self, self.canvas)

    def canvasPressEvent( self, e ):
        point = self.toMapCoordinates(self.canvas.mouseLastXY())
        point = list(point)
        iface.mapCanvas().snappingUtils().toggleEnabled()
        print(point)

canvas_clicked = PrintClickedPoint( iface.mapCanvas() )
iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool( canvas_clicked )
```

Comment: You don't have any reference to the current layer. Maybe that is required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the example below. Paste into a new editor in the Python console, select an active layer (must be a vector layer, since there is no safeguard in the script to handle raster layers etc!) and click run to test.

```py
class PrintSnappedPoint(QgsMapToolEmitPoint):

    def __init__(self, canvas, transform=False):
        self.canvas = canvas
        QgsMapToolEmitPoint.__init__(self, self.canvas)
        self.transform = transform
        self.project = QgsProject.instance()
        self.l = iface.activeLayer()
        self.i = QgsSnapIndicator(self.canvas)
        self.u = self.canvas.snappingUtils()
        self.c = self.u.config()
        self.c.setEnabled(True)
        self.c.setMode(QgsSnappingConfig.AdvancedConfiguration)
        self.s = QgsSnappingConfig.IndividualLayerSettings(True, QgsSnappingConfig.VertexFlag, 25.00,
                    QgsTolerance.Pixels)
        self.c.setIndividualLayerSettings(self.l, self.s)
        self.u.setConfig(self.c)
        
        #Define source and destination crs's and instantiate QgsCoordinateTransform class
        self.src_crs = self.project.crs()
        #Best to change epsg code below to a local projected crs (e.g. UTM)
        self.dst_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:3857')
        self.x_form = QgsCoordinateTransform(self.src_crs, self.dst_crs, self.project)

    def canvasMoveEvent(self, e):
        m = self.u.snapToMap(e.pos())
        self.i.setMatch(m)

    def canvasPressEvent(self, e):
        if self.i.match().type():
            pointxy = self.i.match().point()
        else:
            pointxy = None
        if pointxy:
            if self.transform:
                tr = self.x_form.transform(pointxy)
                point = [tr.x(), tr.y()]
            else:
                point = [pointxy.x(), pointxy.y()]
            print('Point snapped to vertex: {}'.format(point))
            
    def deactivate(self):
        self.s = QgsSnappingConfig.IndividualLayerSettings(False, QgsSnappingConfig.NoSnapFlag, 25.00,
                    QgsTolerance.Pixels)
        self.c.setIndividualLayerSettings(self.l, self.s)
        self.u.setConfig(self.c)


canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
#to transform snapped click-points, pass True as 2nd argument to constructor
T = PrintSnappedPoint(canvas, True)
canvas.setMapTool(T)
```

Edit based on comments:

I have updated the code above to give an example of using `QgsCoordinateTransform` class to transform the the snapped click-point from the project crs to another crs of your choosing. In this example my project crs is epsg:4326 so I transform the point from that to epsg:3857. However, I would recommend changing the epsg code of the destination crs to an accurate local projected crs such as a UTM zone appropriate to your area.

To use the transform function, pass True as the 2nd argument to the constructor of the `PrintSnappedPoint` class constructor. If you don't pass a 2nd argument, the transform parameter will default to False and the snapped points will be printed according to the project crs.

Expected results shown in the gif below:

[image]

Comment: Thank You @Ben Code works perfectly.Can you please suggest how to get X,Y coordinate rather than latitude and longitude?

Comment: No problem @Devenepali. If I understand what you are asking here, the answer is that if you simply use a projected crs you will get XY coordinates instead of geographic degrees. You can also use the `QgsCoordinateTransform` class to do an on-the-fly transformation from the current project crs to any projected crs. I have updated my answer to show an example of how to do this.

Comment: thanks for the reply it works perfectly in  QGIS console environment. As I tried to implanted this feature in the QGIS plugin , I want to press the push bottom and run the above code and get location selected by user. I connected the function to the push bottom making the object of PrintSnappedPoint class with canvas = iface.mapCanvas() object and called canvas.setMapTool(T). But that does not seems getting any effect in QGIS canvas. Should I need to implement multi-threading or should I need to add any other code so that above code can work in plugin environment. Thanks again Ben.